# Mysql: How can i generate unique 13 numbers for existing products

Tags: mysql

Hello guys I have been trying all day to generate unique 13 numbers for existing products in the database. Each product must have an **EAN13 barcode**.
I tried many examples from the internet but none of them give me good results. Does anyone have a solution how to solve this?

I tried this but nothing not working

```
   select cast(  (@n := (13*@n + 100) % 899999999981)+1e12 as char(15)) as num
from   (select @n := floor(rand() * 10e14) ) init,
       (select 1 union select 2) m01,
       (select 1 union select 2) m02,
       (select 1 union select 2) m03,
       (select 1 union select 2) m04,
       (select 1 union select 2) m05,
       (select 1 union select 2) m06,
       (select 1 union select 2) m07,
       (select 1 union select 2) m08,
       (select 1 union select 2) m09,
       (select 1 union select 2) m10,
       (select 1 union select 2) m11,
       (select 1 union select 2) m12,
       (select 1 union select 2) m13,
       (select 1 union select 2) m14,
       (select 1 union select 2) m15,
       (select 1 union select 2) m16,
       (select 1 union select 2) m17,
       (select 1 union select 2) m18,
       (select 1 union select 2) m19,
       (select 1 union select 2) m20,
       (select 1 union select 2) m21,
       (select 1 union select 2) m22
limit 5;
```

How can i now upadte all 12000 rows in existing table with this code above. I try UPDATE but i get error when i try to mix UPDATE and CAST

**Product table structure is:**

```
productid INT(11)
productName Varchar(225)
barcode INT(13)
```

Comment: Can you share the error what you get when you are trying to run update query?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are these numbers for? Are they just internal identifiers? You cannot store a 13 digit integer in an `int`, you would need to use `bigint`.

Comment: SQL is a poor choice of language to do this kind of work. I recommend doing it using an application language and executing simple select/update SQL

Comment: If you change int to bigint, simple update [works](https://dbfiddle.uk/XLhnhkXh).

Comment: That calculation does not create a valid EAN13. The 13th digit is a check digit and needs to be calculated.

Comment: I dont need 100% valid EAN i just need to generate unique 13 digits and my POS accept that like barcode.